# Every eventually sequence is frequently

Tags: sequences-and-series

My teachers said that every eventually sequence is frequently because

If $<x_n>$ is eventually in $A\subset X$ then

$\exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $x_n\in A,\forall n\geq n_0$

Hence $\forall n_1\in \mathbb{N}\ni   n_1\geq n_0$, $\exists n\in n_1$ such that  $x_n\in A$

Therefore $<x_n>$ is frequently in $A$

My problems with this proof it that the definition of a frequently sequence is $\forall n_1\in \mathbb{N}, \exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in A$ and $n\geq n_1$ while this proof only proves for $n_1\geq n_0$ not for all $n_1$. So how it could be enough prove?